# Cannot retrieve Name of user from MYSQL DB... What am I doing wrong?

Tags: python, mysql, flask

Novice Coder here :)

I have a MYSQL DB setup with a 'users' table.  In my Flask application, I'm able to have users create login credentials. When the user logs in, correctly - I want their name {{ session.name }}, not username, show up on the redirected page. Somehow I cannot get it to work. I'm able to show their username, {{ session.username }}, but this is not what I want.

Somehow and somewhere it's not getting the Name from the DB.

I'm not sure if I'm making the correct DB call via sessions.

My DB looks like this:

```html
MariaDB [chrimata]> DESCRIBE users;
+---------------+--------------+------+-----+---------------------+----------------+
| Field         | Type         | Null | Key | Default             | Extra          |
+---------------+--------------+------+-----+---------------------+----------------+
| id            | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL                | auto_increment |
| name          | varchar(100) | YES  |     | NULL                |                |
| email         | varchar(50)  | YES  |     | NULL                |                |
| username      | varchar(30)  | YES  |     | NULL                |                |
| password      | varchar(100) | YES  |     | NULL                |                |
| register_date | timestamp    | NO   |     | current_timestamp() |                |
+---------------+--------------+------+-----+---------------------+----------------+
```

Here is my login code:

```html
@app.route('/login', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def login():
    msg=''
    if request.method == "POST" :
        details = request.form
        Username = details['username']
        Password_candidate = details['password']

        # Check if account exists using MySQL
        cursor = mysql.connection.cursor()
        # Check DB for username...
        result = cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = %s", [Username])

        if not Username and not Password_candidate :
            error = 'Please fill out the form!'
            return render_template('login.html', msg=error)
        if result > 0:
            #get the stored hash
            account = cursor.fetchone()
            password = account['password']
            Name = account['name']

            if Password_candidate == password:
                session['login_in'] = True
                session['username'] = Username
                session['name'] = Name
```

I suspect it's the fetchone() method causing the issue or the DB call before it.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Is an error being generated?

Comment: No error is generated... just doesn't show anything.

Answer (score 0):

You should have got an error message.

If you gave only one parameter, you still ave to put a comma even when nothing comes after.

It is enough that you get only the needed data, and nothing more

```
result = cursor.execute("SELECT name,password FROM users WHERE username = %s", (Username,))
```

last please don't save password in plain text

Comment: @ nbk - No error message at all. Ok, I'll add the comma. Thanks for the password tip. I just didn't add encryption just yet. This is a home-lab project :)